# draw polyline between multiple markers

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have solved the problem of placing multiple marker in google map.
now i have face the problem to draw a polyline between this markers.actually i am new to google map api.
`my code:`

value of `$lat1` is
`[["a, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380001, India","23.0263517","72.5819013"],

  ["b, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India","23.0690035","72.6801576"],
  ["c, Ahmedabad, Gujarat 380015, India","23.0171240","72.5330533"]]`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var markerarray=new Array();
 var locations = <?php echo json_encode($lat1);?>;
 var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 zoom: 10,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.0171240, 72.5330533),
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
{ 
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),

    map: map
   });

 markerarray[i] = (Array(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]));

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
} 

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: markerarray,
  geodesic: true,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
});

flightPath.setMap(map);
</script>
```

I draw polyline using static value.but no success with dynamic value.
i use this example for draw polyline.but i have no idea how to use it with multiple markers.

[Simple Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `$lat1` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

populate an `array` with the `marker`-positions and use this `array` as `path`-option for the `google.maps.Polyline`

Comment: i update my quetion.i populate array with marker position.but not able to use it with `google.maps.Polyline`.

Comment: You did not populate it with the marker-position(what is a LatLng), you populate it with arrays, but the path-array must consist of LatLng's : `markerarray[i] = marker.getPosition();`

Comment: thank you very much. it is solved.and one more thing is it possible to draw a route between markers?

Comment: It's possible, you must use the [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) . Use the first position as `origin`, the last position as `destination` and the other positions(up to 8 are possible) as `waypoints`